# In JSON-LD, is it possible to define a URI mapping for a property value?

Tags: json-ld

Suppose we have the following JSON:

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "status": "http://schema.org/status"
  },
  "name": "Manu Sporny",
  "status": "trollin'"
}
```

([JSON-LD Playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fstatus%22%7D%2C%22name%22%3A%22Manu%20Sporny%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22trollin'%22%7D))

The `trollin'` status is identified with a URI: `http://example.com/trolling`. Is it possible to expand the `trollin'` keyword in the example above to the URI `http://example.com/trolling`?

A straightforward manipulation of the context does not work:

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "status": "http://schema.org/status",
    "trollin'": "http://example.com/trolling"
  },
  "name": "Manu Sporny",
  "status": "trollin'"
}
```

([JSON Playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fstatus%22%2C%22trollin'%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftrolling%22%7D%2C%22name%22%3A%22Manu%20Sporny%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22trollin'%22%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22ical%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F12%2Fcal%2Fical%23%22%2C%22xsd%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%22%2C%22ical%3Adtstart%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3AdateTime%22%7D%7D%7D))

Forcing the type of `status` to `@id` also won't work, because it will assume `trollin'` is a relative URI.

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "status": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/status",
      "@type": "@id"
    },
    "trollin'": "http://example.com/trolling"
  },
  "name": "Manu Sporny",
  "status": "trollin'"
}
```

([JSON-LD Playground](http://json-ld.org/playground/#startTab=tab-nquads&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22status%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fstatus%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40id%22%7D%2C%22trollin'%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftrolling%22%7D%2C%22name%22%3A%22Manu%20Sporny%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22trollin'%22%7D&context=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22ical%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2002%2F12%2Fcal%2Fical%23%22%2C%22xsd%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%23%22%2C%22ical%3Adtstart%22%3A%7B%22%40type%22%3A%22xsd%3AdateTime%22%7D%7D%7D))

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, you can do it, you need to set the type of status to @vocab:

```
{
  "@context":
  {
    "name": "http://schema.org/name",
    "status": {
      "@id": "http://schema.org/status",
      "@type": "@vocab"
    },
    "trollin'": "http://example.com/trolling"
  },
  "name": "Manu Sporny",
  "status": "trollin'"
}
```

Here's a [link](http://json-ld.org/playground/index.html?startTab=tab-expanded&json-ld=%7B%22%40context%22%3A%7B%22name%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fname%22%2C%22status%22%3A%7B%22%40id%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fschema.org%2Fstatus%22%2C%22%40type%22%3A%22%40vocab%22%7D%2C%22trollin'%22%3A%22http%3A%2F%2Fexample.com%2Ftrolling%22%7D%2C%22name%22%3A%22Manu%20Sporny%22%2C%22status%22%3A%22trollin'%22%7D) to the playground.

Comment: Where is this `{"@type": "@vocab"}` described? I can't seem to find it anywhere in the [official JSON-LD spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld/).

UPDATE: I found it: http://lists.w3.org/Archives/Public/public-hydra/2014Sep/0029.html

> After some discussion with Gregg who pointed me to
http://www.w3.org/TR/json-ld-api/#value-expansion, this is the outcome.

> The @vocab keyword has a second meaning which is not mentioned in the
json-ld spec, only in the api. If used as a value of @type in the
context, it says that the corresponding attribute value must be
expanded to an IRI.

Comment: Curious... why it's never mentioned in the JSON-LD spec? Also... the JSON-LD API spec is _very_ cryptic (true RDF style), I can't seem to find exactly where this `{"@type": "@vocab"}` construct is described...

Comment: There are recent improvements to the JSON-LD syntax spec. See https://w3c.github.io/json-ld-syntax/#type-coercion for the uses of `"@type": "@vocab"` in a term definition.