# How to cleanly specify predicate-specific URI scopes in JSON-LD?

Tags: json-ld

I'm starting with [this JSON-LD document](http://json-ld.org/playground/#/gist/30e19e7a88d47a836f38) (json-ld playground), where the meat looks like this:

```
"from": [
  "protein:15718680",
  "protein:157427902"
],
"protein_gene": [
  "gene:522311",
  "gene:3702"
]
```

Now, the "protein_gene" predicate always takes gene identifiers as values. Since there can be hundreds of these, what I really want in the JSON is this:

`"from": [
    "protein:15718680",
    "protein:157427902"
],
"protein_gene": [
    "522311",
    "3702"
]`

without the "gene" prefix everywhere.  Is it possible?  The closest I got, based on [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26633788/in-json-ld-is-it-possible-to-define-a-uri-mapping-for-a-property-value), was [this](http://json-ld.org/playground/#/gist/e17eaaf164610a94c8fd) (json-ld playground). It causes the predicate values to be expanded into IRIs, and not relative IRIs, but those based on the @vocab. But it is not right, because I want a predicate-specific vocab.

I also know that I can play tricks with embedded (local) contexts, and I got [this](http://json-ld.org/playground/#/gist/0948a2251589826433ae) (json-ld playground) to work, but it is still uglier than I would like.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this for a single property, but not multiple (more than two, you can use `@vocab` and `@base` if you have two). Apart from injecting contexts, there's no way to scope `@vocab` and `@base` to a property.

Comment: Thanks, that's what I suspected.